# Regexp in lex. Why does flex behave this way

Tags: regex, lex

Consider a simple integer digit identifying expression like this:

```
[0-9]+ printf("Integer");
```

Now if i give `123` as an input it returns `Integer`, fair enough. Now if I give `s123` as the input it prints out `sInteger`. The unmatched `s` is being printed by default `ECHO` that's cool with me. But why is `Integer` also printed. Shouldn't lex return just `s`? My input is considered as a whole string right? I mean `s123 is considered as a 1 full input`?. As soon as `s` is encountered which does not match `[0-9]+` so it should just `echo default unmatched value s123` but why `sInteger?`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The string `s123` is being matched by the regex `[0-9]+`. If you want to match strings which consist of only integers, you should try `^[0-9]+$`.